How to write Bangla in shap graph
I have used shap on my Bangla dataset and plotted bar graph with following code:
pred = transformers.pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0, return_all_scores=True) 
explainer = shap.Explainer(pred) 
shap_values = explainer(list(X_val)[:5])
shap.plots.bar(shap_values[:, :, '2'].mean(0))

The output is:

The bangla words are not visible in the graph. How can I add Bangla Language here?
I expect some useful sugestions.

Could you please provide minimal reproducible example

pred = transformers.pipeline("text-classification", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0, return_all_scores=True)
explainer = shap.Explainer(pred)
shap_values = explainer(list(X_val)[:5])
shap.plots.bar(shap_values[:, :, '2'].mean0))
This is how I have generated the bar graph. I am working with Bangla Text. Instead of showing texts, it is showing boxes.

This is a font issue. Try a similar example with you language for some labels in matplotlib and see if you have the same issue.

Could you please share some example code if possible?
